# What does "t" in the permissions of the file on Linux indicate?

Tags: linux

When I run the ls -l command on a directory, I see the following permissions for a file and I don't know what does "t" indicate in the permissions?

```
-r-----rwt 1 bruce bruce 28146 Oct 27 09:48 sample
```

sample is an ELF binary and I want to know if I have execute permissions for it.

Comment: Some good reading on the sticky bit (and setuid and setgid).  All 3 related articles are pretty good for an intro on Linux permissions - http://www.filepermissions.com/articles/sticky-bit-suid-and-sgid

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In short: it indicates a sticky bit. On files, it is basically useless these days - it was an optimisation hint for older OSes. It has a rather different meaning for directories.

Lowercase `t` implies `x` while uppercase `T` does not.

---

GNU `ls` is documented in its info pages (`info ls`), also [available on the web](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/What-information-is-listed.html#What-information-is-listed).

> The file mode bits listed are similar to symbolic mode specifications (see Symbolic Modes). But ls combines multiple bits into the third character of each set of permissions as follows:
>
> ...
>
> `t`
>
> If the restricted deletion flag or sticky bit, and the other-executable bit, are both set. The restricted deletion flag is another name for the sticky bit. See [Mode Structure](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Mode-Structure.html#Mode-Structure).
>
> `T`
>
> If the restricted deletion flag or sticky bit is set but the other-executable bit is not set.
>
> `x`
>
> If the executable bit is set and none of the above apply.

Lowercase `t` implies `x` (for *other*; *user* and *group* are shown separately) while uppercase `T` does not.

Which leads us to [the mode structure](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Mode-Structure.html#Mode-Structure):

> In addition to the three sets of three permissions listed above, the file mode bits have three special components, which affect only executable files (programs) and, on most systems, directories:
>
> ...
>
> 3. Prevent unprivileged users from removing or renaming a file in a directory unless they own the file or the directory; this is called the *restricted deletion flag* for the directory, and is commonly found on world-writable directories like /tmp.
>
>    **For regular files on some older systems, save the program’s text image on the swap device so it will load more quickly when run; this is called the *sticky bit*.**

When used on a **file**, it was an [old optimisation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79395/how-does-the-sticky-bit-work#comment116944_79401) that instructs the OS to cache them after they are run. It is no longer relevant in modern OSes.